# Join on any of several columns

Tags: sql

I have a few tables, each containing different columns, which contain different subsets of all the products.
I want to get a list of all the information about all the products, so I want to do a `full outer join` on the `product_id`.

I tried

```
select * from table1
full outer join table2 b on b.product_id = table1.product_id 
...
full outer join tableN c on b.product_id = table1.product_id
```

but this results in multiple rows where a `product_id` does not exist in table1, but might exist in table2 and tableN.
Is there a way to "coalesce" the join column?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: also your join to table alias c is not filtering on c.product_id it is filtering on b.product_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `full outer join` with more than two tables, then you will end up with something like this:

```
select *
from table1 a full outer join
     table2 b
     on b.product_id = a.product_id 
     ... full outer join
     tableN c
     on c.product_id = coalesce(b.product_id, a.product_id)
```

The `using` clause -- supported by Postgres but not SQL Server -- simplifies this.  It does assume that the columns all have the same name.

An alternative is a driving table.  If you don't have a table of all products handy, you can create one:

```
select *
from (select product_id from table1 union
      select product_id from table2 union
      . . .
      select product_id from tableN
     ) driving left join
     table1 a
     on a.product_id = driving.product_id left join
     table2 b
     on b.product_id = driving.product_id 
     ... full outer join
     tableN c
     on c.product_id = driving.product_id;
```

This should be easier to interpret and the `on` clauses are simplified.

Finally, perhaps you just want common columns.  If so, just use `union all`:

```
select product_id, col1, col2, col3 from table1 union all
select product_id, col1, col2, col3 from table2 union all
      . . .
select product_id, col1, col2, col3 from tableN;
```

This prevents the proliferation of columns with `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1
inner join 
(
SELECT * FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table3
UNION ALL ........ 
SELECT * FROM tableN
) N
on N.product_id = table1.product_id
```